# Incorrect image Amazon API

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I have some problems with getting Amazon images. E.g. for this product 
[https://www.amazon.com/Toy-Story-2-Playstation/dp/B00001QER9%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAJHQF37KIEAK4X6FQ%26tag%3Dtradeserviced-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB00001QER9](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00001QER9)

I got this image http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31BDm2VqflL.jpg

I also get the same image for another products, however on real amazon product page image are correct

*EDIT 1: add some code:*

```
var amazonClient = amazonApi.createClient({
  awsTag: worker.name,
  awsId: worker.amazonId,
  awsSecret: worker.amazonSecret
});

amazonClient.itemSearch({
  searchIndex: 'VideoGames',
  keywords: 'ps1',
  itemPage: 0,
  responseGroup: 'Large',
  domain: domain
}).then(function(res) {
  // HERE a half of products hasn't image and has this http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31BDm2VqflL.jpg incorrect image in ImageSet property
})
```

Comment: Could you provide samples of your work (code samples, AWS configs) so we can try to help you ?

Comment: @Valberthe added code example